# How can I reset style on a polygon?

Tags: javascript, polygon, leaflet

I can not get the style to reset on a leaflet polygon. The `setStyle` works just fine on hover, however resetting it when I stop hovering is not working. I'm getting *Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'resetStyle'*. I understand what that error means, but I can't figure out how to properly do this.

Thanks in advance.

```
$.getJSON('geoJSON.json', function (json) {
    L.geoJson(json, {
        ...
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            var defaultStyle = layer.style;

            layer.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                this.setStyle({
                    color: '#2262CC',
                    weight: 3,
                    opacity: 0.6,
                    fillOpacity: 0.65,
                    fillColor: '#2262CC'
                });
            });
            layer.on('mouseout', function (e) {
                this.resetStyle();
            });
        }
    }).addTo(map);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a problem of context:

```
$.getJSON('geoJSON.json', function (json) {
    L.geoJson(json, {
        ...
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            var defaultStyle = layer.style,
                that = this;//NEW

            layer.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                this.setStyle({
                    color: '#2262CC',
                    weight: 3,
                    opacity: 0.6,
                    fillOpacity: 0.65,
                    fillColor: '#2262CC'
                });
            });
            layer.on('mouseout', function (e) {
                that.resetStyle(); //NEW
            });
        }
    }).addTo(map);
});
```

Comment: It's not that I can't figure out a way to juggle styles, it's the fact that resetStyle() isn't working for me.

Comment: Ah. I think I found the problem.

Comment: It may be a problem of context.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Haven't worked on this in a couple weeks. =)

Answer (score 4):

The code above fails because the resetStyle function can be found in the geojson layer and not in the layer that "this" points to.

Also the geojson layer requires a style path option set for the default style for resetStyle to work.

```
$.getJSON('geoJSON.json', function (json) {
    var geojson = L.geoJson(json, {
        ...
        style: <default style here>
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            var defaultStyle = layer.style;

            layer.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                this.setStyle({
                    color: '#2262CC',
                    weight: 3,
                    opacity: 0.6,
                    fillOpacity: 0.65,
                    fillColor: '#2262CC'
                });
            });
            layer.on('mouseout', function (e) {
                geojson.resetStyle();
            });
        }
    }).addTo(map);
});
```